# stderr not being redirected to variable when bash script run from NSTask/Process in Swift

Tags: bash, redirect, command-line, stderr, nstask

**Edit:**

Here is a link to the actual Xcode Test Project:

https://github.com/briggsm/StdErrTest

With this, I think it will be very easy to reproduce & see this issue.

**Original Post:**

I have an executable (`chmod +x`) bash script (`myScript.sh`) like so:

```
#!/bin/sh

# auto login disabled
ald=$(defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow autoLoginUser 2>&1)
echo "ald: $ald"
```

## Command-line Works

If I run this script from the command line, it works perfectly:

```
$ ./myScript.sh 
ald: 2016-11-25 17:13:14.467 defaults[26645:619328] 
The domain/default pair of (/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow, autoLoginUser) does not exist
```

The output came from `stderr`.

## Xcode/Swift - Process/NSTask Does Not Work

But if I run this same script from an App in Xcode, using `Swift 3` and the `Process` class, it does not work - the `stderr` does not seem to be getting redirected to `stdout`, and the variable (`ald`) is just an empty string.

For reference, here is my `ViewController.swift` code:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func runProcessClicked(_ sender: NSButton) {
        // Make sure we can find the script file. Return if not.
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myScript", ofType:".sh") else {
            print("\n  Unable to locate: myScript.sh!")
            return
        }

        // Init outputPipe
        let outputPipe = Pipe()

        // Setup & Launch our process
        let ps: Process = Process()
        ps.launchPath = path
        //ps.arguments = arguments
        ps.standardOutput = outputPipe
        ps.launch()
        ps.waitUntilExit()

        // Read everything the outputPipe captured from stdout
        let data = outputPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        var outputString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? ""
        outputString = outputString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

        // Return the output
        print("[output: \(outputString)]")
    }
}
```

After clicking the button, the output I see is:

```
[output: ald:]
```

If `myScript.sh` runs a command which simply outputs to `stdout`, that value DOES get stored in `ald` and I can see it both from the command-line AND Xcode.

So it appears to me that the issue is that `stderr` is not getting redirected to `stdout` in the context of a process/task being run via Swift.

Can anybody shed some light on this issue, and help me solve this problem? Thank you so much for trying!

Comment: Is `defaults` in your path?

Comment: @123, yes. From command-line definitely yes. From Swift code, I assume so, because if I run another 'defaults read' command (one that uses just stdout), everything works as expected.

Comment: Does it output anything if you don't capture the command and just let it output to STDERR?

Comment: @123, do you mean just take out the '2>&1' from my script and run it? If so, it also outputs nothing.

Comment: No put it outside `$()` and remove the redirection.

Comment: Hi @123, I'm sorry, I cannot quite figure out exactly what you're trying to say. What I 'think' you're saying doesn't make sense, but I'm probably misunderstanding you. Anyhow, I edited my Question, and added a link to my GitHub repo with all my code there. It should be very easy to reproduce this issue on your own machine from that. Thank you for your thoughts & help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129064/discussion-between-briggsm-and-123).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, maybe not so much an "answer" as a "discovery ", but I'll post here in case others find it useful.

If Xcode App is run in Debug mode, it does not work. But if I "Archive" the App and export it to a "macOS App", it DOES work!

Maybe has something to do with App's sandbox environment in the Release version vs the Debug version. I wouldn't think so but apparently it does.

I'd still love to know why it doesn't work in Xcode (in Debug mode) though, because debugging within Xcode is obviously very useful!

Any additional thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but I ran into a similar issue trying to re-direct stderror to a NSTask my program is launching (while debugging).  I found that if I edit the Scheme and under the Options tab change the Console setting from 'Use Xcode' to 'Use Terminal' I am able to successfully redirect stderror and register for notifications while in the debugger.